# How to highlight full row in GNU screen

Tags: macos, gnu-screen

I have a Mac Pro and now I am trying to use GNU screen instead of Terminal.

When I need to look at the log the I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> and I get into copy mode. However it is really hard to detect where my cursor is since it is of color red and it is an underscore. Is it possible to get the cursor in a block form in copy mode? Or highlight the whole row?

Any stronger visual indication of where my cursor is in copy mode would be of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean "use GNU screen instead of terminal". I typically use GNU screen within a window of the standard OS X Terminal app.

If you're using the standard Mac Terminal, you can change the cursor in application preferences -- it can be a block, underline or vertical bar and can blink or not. You can change the color there as well.

When I select text in screen, the text highlights. For example, I hit `Ctrl-A`, then escape, use arrow keys to move up to where I want to start the selection and hit space. Then when I move the cursor around, it highlights the portion I've selected.

Comment: I thought cursor blinking was governed by GNU screen. Thanks. Not it is a block and it is blinking all good